# Convert String to Tuple in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a `variable` passed as an `argument` in BigQuery which is in the format `"('a','b','c')"`

```
with vars as (
select "{0}" as var1,
)
-- where, {0} = "('a','b','c')"
```

To use it in `BigQuery` I need to make it a tuple `('a','b','c')`.
How can it be done?
Any alternate approach is also welcome.

```
Example:
with vars as (
select "('a','b','c')" as index
)

select * from `<some_other_db>.table`  where index  in (
select index from vars)
-- gives me empty results because index is now a string
```

Present output:
select * from `<db_name>.table`  where index  in `"('a','b','c')"`

Required output:
select * from `<db_name>.table`  where index  in `('a','b','c')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT "('a','b','c')" AS var
) 
SELECT *
FROM `<some_other_db>.table` 
WHERE index IN UNNEST((
  SELECT SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(var, r'[()\']', ''))
  FROM vars
))
```

You can test, play with above using some dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT "('a','b','c')" AS var
), `<some_other_db>.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'a' index UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'e'
) 
SELECT *
FROM `<some_other_db>.table` 
WHERE index IN UNNEST((
  SELECT SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(var, r'[()\']', ''))
  FROM vars
))
```

with output

```
Row id  index    
1   1   a    
2   3   c
```

Comment: I tried this but it is showing me error. `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST at [7:1]`

Comment: I just run it (as it is in my answer's test example) and it works as expected. please double check and try again

Comment: Sorry Mikhail Berlyant. Had a mistake from my side only. it is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are asking for:

```
with vars as ( select "('a','b','c')" as var1) 
select as struct
       MAX(CASE WHEN n = 0 then var END) as f1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN n = 1 then var END) as f2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN n = 2 then var END) as f3
from vars v cross join
     unnest(SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(var1, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',')) var with offset n;
```

Comment: Perhaps I am unable to make you understand correctly. Input is "('a','b','c')" and output is ('a','b','c'). And number of elements in tuple can be varying.

Comment: @AnirbanMalick - update your question with more details of your case and clear explanation of what is expected  - so we will be able to help