# BigQuery `LIKE ANY` and `NOT LIKE ANY`

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Try to understand the BigQuery behaviour of the `ANY` operator (see also [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators)

The following statement returns as expected true:

```
SELECT 'a'      LIKE ANY ('b','%b%', 'b', 'a');
--true
```

It basically answers the question, is there any 'a' in the pattern, yes it is!

Now inverting the statement also returns true:

```
SELECT 'a'  NOT LIKE ANY ('b','%b%', 'b', 'a');
-- true
```

In this case the question would be is there not any 'a' in the pattern, which is false, there is a 'a' in the pattern.

Can somebody help me to understand the behaviour of BigQuery? thanks!

Was reading throw the documentation which states: ANY: Checks if the set of patterns contains at least one pattern that matches the search value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the second query asks the database if in the tupel are elements that are not a

And as there are 3 You get true.

For what you are searching is `NOT IN`

Comment: `NOT IN` does not support patterns. Using subquery would be one option, but is there a solution without subquery in the where clause?

Comment: Not in supports tupely you conconvert a string into a tupel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355001/convert-string-to-tuple-in-bigquery

Comment: Solved my real world problem with `not like all`, but good to know. Thanks